# String failing evaluation as PHP causing blank/white page

Tags: php-errors, phpstringfun

We have a page on our new EE site which is failing to load (blank/white page) because of a PHP error which I'm having some difficulty troubleshooting.

The page is at http://www.healthyschoolscampaign.org/programs/health-in-mind/, and the error encountered is:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Please contact support about failure
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 683

Those familiar will know that line 683 is the function which evaluates a string as PHP. Unfortunately, due to the vagueness of the error message, I'm not sure how to tell what data is being passed as the string. I do know that other pages use the same Structure Template as this page and do not throw the same error.

We have other seemingly random blog pages which fail to load for the exact same reason, but it is not consistent across all blog entries. Any help would be appreciated, as I'm pretty much a PHP n00b.

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: Another page which uses the same template and loads without issue is http://www.healthyschoolscampaign.org/programs/green-clean-schools/

Comment: Which version of EE are you using? Also, you make mention of Structure. Which version of this do you have installed and how are you using it? You mention "blog pages" but usually you have "blog entries" or "structure pages". Are you using Structure for each one of your blog entries?

Comment: You should post your template. It sounds like a conditional gone awry.

Comment: We are using EE v2.5.5, and the version of Structure we are using is 3.3.8. I'm not sure I can really describe how we are using Structure. I know that our blog pages have a Structure tab which is where one would choose the Structure Template (this is the template I should submit, right?)

Comment: When we create a blog entry, it is part of the "Blogs" channel, and not "Blog pages". On the Publish tab of Blogs, when editing or creating an entry, there is a Structure Listing URL, and there is also a Structure tab available, amongst other tabs (Publish, Date, Options, etc. are all what I am calling tabs here).

Comment: Is this working now? The link above seems to resolve to a working page. Did you discover the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Structure URL is correct and unique. Or try creating the entry again.

Comment: We tried recreating one of our blog pages with this issue (as it has less information and takes less time than this page would), and we still encounter the same problem. As near as I can tell, the Structure URL is unique and follows the same convention as all of our other working program pages. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that the url title and the structure url are exactly the same.

Although it's not a perfect fix, if you turn off PHP Warnings does the page load normally?

Comment: the URL title and Structure URL are exactly the same, so that's ruled out. I will have to see about turning off PHP warnings..